# How to SELECT count(*) FROM Table and add a value of 1 onto it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a new row and I would like a column id to be made for the new row. I would like the column id to be the number of all rows before it added together, and then with the number one added to it. So if there was 6 rows, and I added a new one, the column id for the newly added row would be 7. I am trying to use this code:

```
$columnid = "SELECT count(*) FROM careers + 1";

$sql = "INSERT INTO careers ".
       "(job_pos, columnid) ".
       "VALUES('$job_pos', '$columnid')";
```

So far when I added a new row (there was 1 existing row in the table) the column id was 0. I believe it should have been 2.

Whole Page Code:

```
 <?php
// connect to db
$conn = mysqli_connect("s","a","a","a") or die(mysqli_error());
$db = mysqli_select_db('s',$conn) or die(mysqli_error());

// if an arrow link was clicked...
if ($_GET['dir'] && $_GET['id']) {
   // make GET vars easier to handle
   $dir = $_GET['dir'];
   // cast as int and couple with switch for sql injection prevention for $id
   $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
   // decide what row we're swapping based on $dir
   switch ($dir) {
      // if we're going up, swap is 1 less than id
      case 'up': 
         // make sure that there's a row above to swap
         $swap = ($id > 1)? $id-- : 1;
         break;
      // if we're going down, swap is 1 more than id
      case 'down':
         // find out what the highest row is
         $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM careers";
         $result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysqli_error());
         $r = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
         $max = $r[0];
         // make sure that there's a row below to swap with
         $swap = ($id < $max)? $id++ : $max;
         break;
      // default value (sql injection prevention for $dir)
      default:
         $swap = $id;
   } // end switch $dir
   // swap the rows. Basic idea is to make $id=$swap and $swap=$id 
   $sql = "UPDATE careers SET job_pos_sort = CASE job_pos_sort WHEN $id THEN $swap WHEN $swap THEN $id END WHERE job_pos_sort IN ($id, $swap)";
   $result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysqli_error());
} // end if GET  

// set a result order with a default (sql infection prevention for $sortby)
$sortby = ($_GET['sortby'] == 'job_pos')? $_GET['sortby'] : 'job_pos_sort';
// pull the info from the table
$sql = "SELECT job_pos_sort, job_pos FROM careers ORDER BY $sortby";
$result = mysqli_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysqli_error());

// display table
echo "<table border = '1'>";
echo "<tr>";
// make column names links, passing sortby
echo "<td><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sortby=job_pos_sort'>job_pos_sort</a></td>";
echo "<td><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?sortby=job_pos'>job_pos</a></td>";
echo "</tr>";
// display data 1 row at a time
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<tr>";
   // make the links to change custom order, passing direction and the custom sort id
   echo "<td align = 'center'><a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?dir=up&id={$r['job_pos_sort']}'>/\</a> ";
   echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?dir=down&id={$r['job_pos_sort']}'>\/</a></td>";
   echo "<td>{$r['job_pos']}</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
} // end while $r
echo "</table>";
// end display table
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Manage Careers</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
$dbhost = 'a';
$dbuser = 'a';
$dbpass = 'a';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}

if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $job_pos = addslashes ($_POST['job_pos']);
}
else
{
   $job_pos = $_POST['job_pos'];
}

   $columnid_query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT MAX(job_pos_sort) FROM careers");
   $columnid_array=mysqli_fetch_row($columnid_query);
   $newcolumnid=$columnid_array[0]+1;

$sql = "INSERT INTO careers (job_pos, job_pos_sort) VALUES('$job_pos', '$newcolumnid')";
mysqli_select_db('as');
$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysqli_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Job Position</td>
<td><input name="job_pos" type="text" id="job_pos"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add Job Position">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Michael

Comment: Set the field up as autoincrement and let the db do the work for you.

Comment: as @Dan says, otherwise you would need to wrap the select and insert statements in a serializable transaction.

Comment: Docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I would prefer not to use auto increment. Thank you, though.

Comment: Why would you not want to use autoincrement?

Comment: Because I am allowing the user to move each row up or down using an arrow button on a PHP table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommended: make columnid primary key and add auto increment to it in mysql table structure.

otherwise you have to:

```
   $columnid_query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT MAX(columnid) FROM careers");
   $columnid_array=mysqli_fetch_row($columnid_query);
   $newcolumnid=$columnid_array[0]+1;

   mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO careers (job_pos, columnid) VALUES('$job_pos', '$newcolumnid')";
```

Comment: I will check to see if that works later tonight, I have got to run for now. Thank you, though!

Comment: I am getting the error "Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in /home/www/thetotempole.ca/phptester/upanddowntestr.php on line 90

Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in /home/www/thetotempole.ca/phptester/upanddowntestr.php on line 91
Entered data successfully" when using your code. I could post my whole page's code into my question if that would help you answer.

Comment: you seem not to have opened a connection to your database, or the database connection handle isn't called $conn. please post your code

Comment: You're selecting DB after running the queries! try this to connect $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); and remove all your mysqli_select_db

Comment: why are you connecting twice to the DB, once at the top of the code then once at inside if($_POST

Answer (score 2):

You can do this all in one query, using `insert . . . select` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO careers(job_pos, columnid)
    select $job_pos, count(*) + 1
    from careers;
```

The need to do this, though, suggests that `columnid` should probably be auto_incremented.  Then the database would automatically increment the value for each insert.

Comment: Using `count` is a flawed approach, as when rows are added and deleted, the same count may re-occur. Instead, you would have to use `max` but I think an auto-increment column is the correct way.

Comment: @Turophile . . . I totally agree, which is why I suggested an auto-increment column.  Of course, I am only guessing that the purpose of doing `count(*)+1` is to create a unique id.  A better expression would be `max(columnid) + 1`, but I was simply responding to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options in order of preference:

1. Make  columnid PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT. Then you don't have to find MAX value, MySQL will do it for you
2. INSERT SELECT as Gordon Linoff suggests
3. BEGIN; SELECT MAX(columnid) ... ; INSERT  - but all in one transaction, otherwise you may get duplicate key errors.